# Button Disable not working - was working with input

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small jquery that disables button on submit to prevent double clicking.  I added a the button_disable class to my input buttons (I sometimes have multiple buttons on a form) and have a utility script I include with all my pages.

```
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $('.button_disable').attr("disabled", true);
         }
    });
```

I was styling it as an HTML 5 button, and everything was working.

```
<input class="button_next button_disable" type="submit" value="Verify Eligibility" />
```

But now that our css guy changed everything to buttons

```
<button type="submit" class="submitBtn button_disable"><span>Verify Eligibility</span></button>
```

It no longer works.  Debugging shows that the code executes, it just doesn't disable the button.
I've also tried modifying my disable to

```
        $('.button_disable').attr({ "disabled": true });
```

Which does not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `.prop` : `$('.button_disable').prop({ "disabled": true });`

Comment: Does your form submit reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `prop()` if you are using jquery version 1.6+

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('.button_disable').prop("disabled", true);
       return true;
     }
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.button_disable').prop('disabled', true);
```